# How to change vibrate mode to ringer prgrammatically through audio manager

Tags: android

I am making application where phone mode will changes from silent mode to ringer mode if the user sends an sms with some specific keyword. The application mainly works when user lost his cell somewhere in house and its on silent mode.
My main question is how can i change the phone mode through audio manager ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

set SILENT mode to Normal mode using `AudioManager`

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);   

switch (am.getRingerMode()) {   
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:   
        Log.i("MyApp","Silent mode");
        am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        break;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

Comment: & Vineet : Thanks for the help but "getSystemService" is an undefined, can you pls tell me what to do with that ??

Comment: `getSystemService` is a method of the `Context` class. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. But i actually got i actually got my solution from this ::

AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
          int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

          audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
          audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);

Answer (score 0):

To make it work for android devices for and above Marshmallow(API 23)

1. In `AndroidManifest.xml` define the `ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY` permission

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
   ```
2. In your `onResume/onCreate` function ask for permission if not granted

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       //Check if the phone is running Marshmallow or above
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
           //If the permission is not granted, launch an inbuilt activity to grant permission
           if (!nm.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
               startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Finally to change Ringer mode call this method

   ```
   public void setRingerMode(Context context,int mode){
           /*
           * mode variable value can be:
           * AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT
           * AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL
           * AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE
           */
           NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
           AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
           if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M && nm.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted())
               audioManager.setRingerMode(mode);
       }
   ```